# Removing Chrome style for input text (list)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to build a custom input text list. I have an image I would like to use as arrow, so that I can click and show the list of values.
I am also using AngularJS.

The following code does not work as expected. My issue is: I see a black arrow on the left of the yellow arrow when passing over or clicking (otherwise no arrow)

Here's a link to try it (no yellow arrow is shown, but there is some white space on the right of the undesired black arrow): http://jsfiddle.net/wbo3pt9u/

[image]

Here's the code.

```
<input type="text" list="typeL" ng-model="tipo" class="list" placeholder="Type">
    <datalist id="typeL">
    <option ng-repeat="objectType in objectTypes"
                            value="{{objectType.typeWorkOfArt}}" } />
</datalist>
</input>
```

CSS:

```
.list {
    background: url('../images/arrow.png') no-repeat top right;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 160px;
    height: 33px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 2px solid #c1c4c6;
    line-height: 29px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 1.250em;
    padding:0 30px 0 10px !important;
    color: #58585A;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
}

.input {
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 160px;
    height: 33px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 2px solid #c1c4c6;
    line-height: 29px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 1.250em;
    padding: 0 1em;
    color: #58585A;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

I also tried to use a , which worked correctly: no black arrow and single click. Now that I switched to this element, it does not work. How can I fix it?

Comment: Try to create a code snippet or a jsfiddle so we can see the issue. If you want more control over a selectiong styling, have a look at the select2 library

Comment: Updated my post: http://jsfiddle.net/wbo3pt9u/

Answer (score 1):

Solved by introducing this CSS lines:

```
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;
}
```